# Writing to DataFrame in chunks as rows are generated

Tags: python, pandas

I am generating ~20K form objects from images, transcribing them into pandas DataFrame rows, and then exporting the DataFrame to csv.

```
forms = [generate_form(image_data) for image_data in data_pool]
df = pd.DataFrame([form.as_dict() for form in forms])
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

As the `generate_form` function takes a few seconds to execute and is susceptible to failure, I want to export the DataFrame in chunks as the form data is being generated to create checkpoints and ensure I don't lose everything if an unexpected error occurs.

I would appreciate suggestions how to achieve this.

Comment: When you say "`generate_form` function takes a few seconds to execute..." and you have ~20K forms, so the overall `[generate_form(image_data) for image_data in data_pool]` might take 16 hours or more? (20K X 3 seconds is 16.667 hours...)

Comment: That's right, which is why my current implementation is dangerous. I need to create checkpoints of sorts.

Comment: Perhaps use a data serializer such as PICKLE that saves each or groups of data as converted and then convert to CSV from that serialized data. If the operation is interrupted you can recover right where you were interrupted.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a generator that yields the forms one at a time and is robust regarding failure of the `generate_form` function.
In the example below this generator is created by calling `generate_all_forms`. The function `write_forms` retrieves the forms one at a time and writes them to a csv file (optionally in chunks) by specifying `mode='a'` when calling `to_csv`.
You likely also want to log which images were/weren't processed successfully to retry the failed ones later.

```py
def generate_all_forms(data_pool):

    for image_id, image_data in enumerate(data_pool):

        try:
            form = generate_form(image_data)
        except:
            form = None

        yield image_id, form


def write_forms(forms, path, chunk_size=1):

    chunk = []
    header = True
    for image_id, form in forms:

        if form is None:
            # log failure for image_id

        else:

            chunk.append(form)

            if len(chunk) == chunk_size:
                pd.DataFrame(chunk).to_csv(path, mode='a', header=header)
                chunk = []
                header = False  # only write header the first time

            # log success for image_id

    # make sure to append the last chunk
    if len(chunk) > 0:
        pd.DataFrame(chunk).to_csv(path, mode='a', header=header)


write_forms(forms=generate_all_forms(data_pool),
            path='tmp.csv',
            chunk_size=3)

results = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
```

More background on generators is available [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#).